# android studio closes automatically after few seconds of start

Tags: 14.04, android-studio

I have installed android studio in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have set up everything. After that when I try to open it closes automatically. Any solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed **JDK** in order to have a fully functional Studio?

Comment: I have installed this "openjdk-7-jdk" before installing android-studio

Comment: Can I have the output for `echo $JAVA_HOME` please? Open a terminal and type this, let me know the output

Comment: $ echo $JAVA_HOME shows nothing. Empty

Comment: can I have the output for `java -version` and `which java`, please?

Comment: It is returning Blank line.

Comment: $java -version   shows this                                                                                        java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: $which java shows this /usr/bin/java

Comment: Seems like you java is functional but exporting path is not set to have the studio opened.

Comment: Did you enable java after installing with `update-alternatives --display java` ?

Comment: export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/java/"
placed these two lines in .profile and exported.  but still result is same

Comment: If your java has inherited the path it would have shown by now when you entered the command `echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: And also you're missing the jvm and jdk path... you have to specify the path properly...

Comment: I have not enabled java before with     update-alternatives --display java   did it now.  but still the same result.

Comment: can you post a screen of `sudo update-alternatives --config java` & sudo update-alternatives --config javac` while configuring.. I would like to see the locations of it. Just post screen shot of them.

Comment: I have included "export JAVA_HOME = $JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386 " in .profile now echo $JAVA_HOME shows /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386.

Comment: Can you try the studio now?

Comment: No same problem.

Comment: How did you install the Studio.. was it manual or you have done it through **PPA's**..? Have a look at > https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/132-mobile/779326-mobile-development-how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-version-1404

Comment: I have downloaded zip file from google android developer site. I will try from PPA. Thank you. I Hope it should work.

Comment: Please post back... Meanwhile, let me have a quick read as I've been out with these for sometime.. Coz, I do run an android service but very rarely I touch them.

Comment: I have installed android studio from PPA. But the result is same.it closes after creating a new project.

Comment: It worked! Installing oracle java jdk solved the issue. Thank you for your concern